# Facebook PHP SDK: Post attached photo to fanpage

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, attachment, photo

in my working code to post a message with url-based image, i have this setup:

```
   $post_data = array(
    'message' => 'nice kitten pic',
    'url' => 'http://www.eastcottvets.co.uk/uploads/Animals/gingerkitten.jpg'
    );
   $request = new FacebookRequest($app, $access_token, 'POST', '/' . $page_id . '/photos', $post_data);
```

i tryed this, which does not work:

```
$post_data = array(
    'message' => 'nice kitten pic',
    'source' => realpath('pics/kitten.jpg')
    );
```

But now i like to post an image, not with an url reference, but with a reference to the path of the image on my localhost.
Facebook Docu says:

"*There are two separate ways of publishing photos to Facebook:
1: Attach the photo as multipart/form-data. The name of the object doesn't matter, but historically people have used source as the parameter name for the photo. How this works depends on the SDK you happen to be using to do the post.
2: Use a photo that is already on the internet by publishing using the url parameter:*"

So, way Nr.2 works, but how do i use way nr.1, with "attach the photo as multipart/form-data" ?? - the docu laks an example for php sdk and in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the docu laks an example for php sdk and in general.

No, it doesn’t – you’ve just missed it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_upload_photo

The part most relevant to your question is the use of the [`fileToUpload`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0#file-to-upload) to prepare a local file for upload.

Comment: thank you verry much, i'm now getting more familar with the structure of the documentation. there where a lot of tutorials in the web , that seems to be outdated, who confused me aswell:))

Answer (score 1):

Solution, for people wo might search aswell:

```
  $post_data = array(
    'message' => 'nice kitten pic',
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/var/www/myPublicToTheWebFolder/kitten.jpg'),
  );
```

of course the path will be different, depending on server setup. but it has to be the full path you have to output there.